# Pagination for product listing pages

Tags: php, pagination

I am building a shop taking products from a txt file and I want to create pagination for the product listing pages.

The code I am using to pull the products and display them is:

```
<?php
// get local file
$p = file_get_contents('mytxtfile.txt');
// turn file into an array, line by line
$ar = explode("\n",$p);
// setup count for how many products there are
$found = 0;
// loop through products
for($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++){
    $product = explode("|",$ar[$i]);

    if( 
    (strpos(slug($product[9]),$_GET['slug']) !== false ) ||
    (strpos(slug($product[10]),$_GET['slug']) !== false ) ||
    (strpos(slug($product[21]),$_GET['slug']) !== false )   

    ){

    // the product numbers below correspond to the column number in the CSV
        $found++; // increment the number of files found
echo '<div class="item">';

echo '<a href="/'.slug($product[21]).'/'.slug($product[1]).'.htm"><img src="'.$product[5].'" /></a>';

echo '<h3><a href="/'.slug($product[21]).'/'.slug($product[1]).'.htm">'.substr($product[1], 0, 70).'</a></h3>';

if (slug($product[8]) == slug($product[7])){    
echo '<p class="price">Only $'.($product[7]).'</p>';

}
else {
echo '<p class="price"><del>Was $'.($product[8]).'</del> NOW Only $'.($product[7]).'</p>';
}

echo '</div>';

        if($found > 101){
            break;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

This will display my products upto the break but I want to show all products. Some categories have a lot of products and I want to keep the page load time down.

Comment: I'd very strongly recommend just using a database as opposed to a text file. This topic itself has been covered extensively on SO. This pagination is also something that is much easier to accomplish in SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery plugin datatables with mysql. What is stated above by glasseye is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work

```
<?php
// get local file
$p = file_get_contents('mytxtfile.txt');
// turn file into an array, line by line
$ar = explode("\n",$p);

// setup count for how many products there are
$found = 0;
if ($_POST['variable'] == '') 
{ 
$perpage = '22'; 
} 
else 
{ 
$perpage = $_POST['variable'] ; 
} 

$current = 0;

$page = (isset($_REQUEST['p']) ? $_REQUEST['p'] : 0  );
// loop through products
for($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++){
    $product = explode("|",$ar[$i]);

    // the product numbers below correspond to the column number in the CSV
    if(strpos($product[19],'BRAND') !== false){

        $found++; // increment the number of files found

                $start = ($page * $perpage);        
        $end = $start + $perpage;
        if( ($found > $start) && ($found < $end)  ){    

echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<a href="/'.slug($product[21]).'/'.slug($product[1]).'.htm"><img src="'.$product[5].'" /></a>';

echo '<h3><a href="/'.slug($product[21]).'/'.slug($product[1]).'.htm">'.substr($product[1], 0, 70).'</a></h3>';

if (slug($product[13]) == ''){  
}
else {
echo '<p>Size = '.$product[13].'</p>'; 
}   

if (slug($product[8]) == slug($product[7])){    
echo '<p class="price">Only $'.($product[7]).'</p>';

}
else {
echo '<p class="price"><del>Was $'.($product[8]).'</del> NOW Only $'.($product[7]).'</p>';
}

echo '</div>';

            }

        }

}

echo '<div class="pagi">'.$found.' Results &raquo; ';
?>

<script>
    choose: function() {
        option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
            if(option[d].selected == true) {
                document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
        } if(this.form.name=='perpage') {this.form.submit();}
    }
}
</script>
Show per page
<form name="perpage" action="index.php" method="post"> 
<select name="variable" onchange="this.form.submit()" /> 
<option disabled selected>22</option>
<option value="50">50</option> 
<option value="100">100</option> 
<option value="200">200</option> 
</select> 
</form> 

Page: 

<?php
$totalpages = ($found / $perpage) + 1;

for($i = 1; $i < $totalpages; $i++){
echo '<a href="index.php?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
}
?>

</div>
```

I think databasing would be easier. Thanks for your advice guys!